# IPv6 down with "NoAddrAvail" and "NoPrefixAvail" after changing WAN interface

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, systemd, ubuntu-server

This all started when I changed modems, which also necessitated changing WAN interfaces on my custom router (1G to 2.5G). The first time I changed the interface, I stopped getting a delegated prefix and started seeing 'NoPrefixAvail' or 'No prefix available on Link' in Wireshark. The second time I tried changing interfaces, for testing purposes, I started getting 'NoAddrAvail' or 'No address available on Link'. I now have no IPv6 connectivity whatsoever, whereas everything worked fine before switching interfaces.

These errors suggest that the problem is on my ISP's side, however, when I switch back to my old off-the-shelf router, I do get an address and prefix.

About my router: I am using Ubuntu Server, with firewalld as a firewall. I request a prefix through systemd as per https://erik.nygren.org/dhcpv6-pd-on-ubuntu-2204.html by adding /etc/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp4s0.network.d/override.conf (where enp4s0 is the WAN interface) containing the following:

```
[Match]

Name=enp4s0


[DHCPv6]

PrefixDelegationHint=::/60
```

This setup worked perfectly for the previous interface, but not for the new ones.

Wireshark caps for 'dhcpv6' are [here](https://pasteb.in/?f205dedc559ab0a2#x9BvU2UWRZgfZDXkacs82LaVrGxiKMEM1vL2FZeYjVS).

Comment: Could it be you have to register the MAC of your new router with your ISP ? Or you could try cloning your old MAC on your new router if the device allows it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an unsatisfying solution, the problem appears to have resolved itself. I randomly ended up with an address and prefix last night.